# Diagonal array input

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, pascal, freepascal

I have a 2D array (`StartingArray`) NxN (for example 3x3). I would like my 2 other arrays (`LRotateArray` and `RRotateArray`) to be `StartingArray` rotated by 45 degrees left and right (each line in `LRotateArray` and `RRotateArray` are diagonals in `StartingArray`):

```
StartingArray:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

LRotateArray:
1
4 2
7 5 3
8 6
9

RRotateArray:
7
4 8
1 5 9 
2 6
3
```

I want to edit `LRotateArray` and `RRotateArray` while getting input to `StartingArray`.

I found a formula allowing me to generate `LRotateArray`:

```
if StartingArray[i][j]=k then L_j=i+j
if j>(N-1-i) then  L_i=N-i-j else L_i=i
LRotateArray[L_i][L_j]=k
```

Is there any easy way to transform `LRotateArray` into `RRotateArray`, or do I have to find another formula like the one above?

Comment: Getting RRotateArray from the StartingArray is a lot easier than getting it from LRotateArray. So I suggest you find another formula for this. However regarding your current formula, I have no idea how it would work and some of it (L_i=N=i-j) just does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO building `RRotateArray` from `StartingArray` is easier than building it from `LRotateArray`. This is how I would implement both rotations:

```
for Row := 0 to N - 1 do
begin
  for Col := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    LeftRow := Col + Row;
    LeftCol := Min(Col, N - 1 - Row);
    LRotateArray[LeftCol, LeftRow] := StartingArray [Col, Row];

    RightRow := Col + (N - Row - 1);
    RightCol := Min(Col, Row);
    RRotateArray[RightCol, RightRow] := StartingArray [Col, Row];
  end;
end;
```